# Trying to create my first script, looking for guidance

Tags: scripting

I am trying to create a script in Blender to optimize a project, but as I have never created a script in Blender, I need some guidance.

What I want to do is select a number of objects, (a few hundred, but less than a thousand)

1. for each of the objects selected, create a small cube at each of their individual locations with the cubes in a separate collection
2. put a rigid body constraint on each of the cubes created with "type" set to "generic spring" and the 2 connected for the constraint to be set to the cube, and the object it was spawned from.
3. have the constraints other settings be copied from those on the active object

If someone could tell me the general steps (or more) the code should take to do all this it would be really great.

edit: also, just to be clear, I'm not asking of anyone to do this for me. and so far, I have gotten my code to get all the selected objects to become rigid bodies,

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions, but as separate posts.

Comment: Instead of asking the community to write the script for you, why don't you actually try to learn how to do it? Quick pointer - click the Scripting workspace button at the top. There you will find an editor to quickly write and test your script, templates to get you started, an Info window that literally tells you what commands to use to perform the action you just did in the 3d view, and an interactive console to try commands out.